# Vanilla JavaScript solution to make a fluid menu tab active state?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/pezemX?editors=0010), and trying to find a vanilla JS way to do this (my company doesn't use jQuery).

So far I've made the line the correct width when you click on a menu item, but I can't figure out how to make it stretch like in the Codepen. I added a custom attribute of `index` to keep track of numbers, and also applied a class to easily target the element. I wasn't sure if there's also a way to just have one. Feel free to change what I've already made.

EDIT: I updated the code below to make it work going left, but not right. Also it only works if the links are next to each other. Anyone?

My codepen: https://codepen.io/ahoward-mm/pen/jOmgxQJ?editors=0010 (desktop only).

```js
var navList = document.querySelector(".navigation__list");
var navItems = navList.getElementsByClassName("navigation__item");
var navLine = document.querySelector(".navigation__line");

for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
  navItems[i].classList.add(`navigation__item--${i + 1}`);
  navItems[i].setAttribute("index", `${i + 1}`);

  var prevItem = 0;
  var currentItem = 1;

  navItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    this.className += " active";

    prevItem = currentItem;

    currentItem = this.getAttribute("index");

    navLine.style.width = `${
      document
        .querySelector(`.navigation__item--${currentItem}`)
        .querySelector(".navigation__link")
        .getBoundingClientRect().width +
      document
        .querySelector(`.navigation__item--${prevItem}`)
        .getBoundingClientRect().width
    }px`;

    navLine.style.left = `${
      this.querySelector(".navigation__link").offsetLeft
    }px`;

    setTimeout(function() {
      navLine.style.width = `${
        document
          .querySelector(`.navigation__item--${currentItem}`)
          .querySelector(".navigation__link")
          .getBoundingClientRect().width
      }px`;
    }, 700);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #444;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navigation {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: -0.5px;
  background-color: #edece8;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation__link {
  color: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px (20px * 2) 0 (20px * 2);
  position: relative;
}

.navigation__line {
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.navigation__item {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Consectetur adipiscing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Donec ut</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Placerat dignissim</a>
    </li>
    <div class="navigation__line"></div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you make a working example of your current implementation?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ahoward-mm/pen/jOmgxQJ?editors=0010 (not mobile friendly)

Comment: just a suggestion for class manipulation in vanillajs, `element.classList` is very handy. It supports `add() remove() toggle() contains()` methods which are super-convenient  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

Idk what your JavaScript code did, so I just decided to convert the `jQuery` code from codepen to vanilla `JavaScript` from scratch. And it works.
(It was a good 2-2.5 hrs exercise.)

So, what I did is converted jQuery to its Vanilla JavaScript Equivalent.
For Ex: `$()` => `document.querySelector()`, `elem.addClass()` => `elem.classList.add()`, `elem.find()` => `elem.querySelectorAll()`, `elem.css({prop: val})` => `elem.style.prop = val;` etc.

```js
var nav = document.querySelector(".navigation");
var navLine = nav.querySelector(".navigation__line");

var pos = 0;
var wid = 0;

function setUnderline() {
  var active = nav.querySelectorAll(".active");
  if (active.length) {
    pos = active[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
    wid = active[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    navLine.style.left = active[0].offsetLeft + "px";
    navLine.style.width = wid + "px";
  }
}

setUnderline()

window.onresize = function() {
  setUnderline()
};

nav.querySelectorAll("ul li a").forEach((elem) => {
  elem.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.parentElement.classList.contains("active") &&
      !nav.classList.contains("animate")
    ) {
      nav.classList.add("animate");

      var _this = this;

      nav
        .querySelectorAll("ul li")
        .forEach((e) => e.classList.remove("active"));

      try {

        var position = _this.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        var width = position.width;

        if (position.x >= pos) {
          navLine.style.width = position.x - pos + width + "px";
          setTimeout(() => {
            navLine.style.left = _this.parentElement.offsetLeft + "px";
            navLine.style.width = width + "px";
            navLine.style.transitionDuration = "150ms";
            setTimeout(() => nav.classList.remove("animate"), 150);
            _this.parentElement.classList.add("active");
          }, 300);
        } else {
          navLine.style.width = pos - position.left + wid + "px";
          navLine.style.left = _this.parentElement.offsetLeft + "px";
          setTimeout(() => {
            navLine.style.width = width + "px";
            navLine.style.transitionDuration = "150ms";
            setTimeout(() => nav.classList.remove("animate"), 150);
            _this.parentElement.classList.add("active");
          }, 300);
        }
      } catch (e) {}
      pos = position.left;
      wid = width;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #444;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navigation {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: -0.5px;
  background-color: #edece8;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

li.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.navigation__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation__link {
  color: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px (20px * 2) 0 (20px * 2);
  position: relative;
}

.navigation__line {
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  left: 0;
}

.navigation__item {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation__list">
      <li class="navigation__item active">
        <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Dolor</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Consectetur adipiscing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Donec ut</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Placerat dignissim</a>
      </li>
      <div class="navigation__line"></div>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @ashlward Welcome. I updated my answer, where I fixed an error.

Comment: occasionally on refresh, Lorem Ipsum is only half underlined to start with.

Comment: @ashlward I am not able to reproduce the issue. But I see, half underline appears when the browser is resized (small -> big).

Comment: @ashlward I have updated the answer rn. Please check if that works.

Comment: I think the problem was coming from my codepen, but I think it's working now.

Answer (score -1):

So, your code works fine for when you're switching to a link that's before the current one. The problem is that when you change to a link that's ahead, you need to adjust the `left` property only after you adjust the `width`.

I made multiple changes in the code for clarity and correctness. Like using `classList` to add/remove classes and `dataset` for custom HTML attributes.

However, the only functional change is to check if the previous item is ahead of the current one, and if it is, only apply the `left` adjustment later, after the `width` adjustment.

Edit: I just realized that there was second issue with the code. The second aspect that wasn't working as desired was when moving multiple links ahead or behind, the line wouldn't expand long enough. I updated the snippet to account for that by calculating the distance from the link that's earlier to the link that's later, plus the width of the later link.

```js
var navList = document.querySelector(".navigation__list");
var navItems = navList.querySelectorAll(".navigation__item");
var navLine = document.querySelector(".navigation__line");

var prevItem = 0;
var currentItem = 1;

navItems.forEach((navItem, i) => {
  navItem.classList.add(`navigation__item--${i + 1}`);
  navItem.dataset.index = i + 1;
  navItem.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var current = document.querySelector(".active");

    if (current) {
      current.classList.remove("active");
    }

    this.classList.add("active");

    prevItem = currentItem;

    currentItem = this.dataset.index;
    
    var movingAhead = currentItem > prevItem;
    
    var aheadElem = movingAhead ? document.querySelector(`.navigation__item--${currentItem} .navigation__link`) : document.querySelector(`.navigation__item--${prevItem}  .navigation__link`);
        var behindElem = movingAhead ? document.querySelector(`.navigation__item--${prevItem}  .navigation__link`) : document.querySelector(`.navigation__item--${currentItem} .navigation__link`);
    navLine.style.width = `${(aheadElem.offsetLeft - behindElem.offsetLeft) + aheadElem.getBoundingClientRect().width
    }px`;
    if (!movingAhead) {
      navLine.style.left = `${this.querySelector(".navigation__link").offsetLeft}px`;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      var currentLink = document.querySelector(`.navigation__item--${currentItem} .navigation__link`);
      navLine.style.width = `${
        currentLink.getBoundingClientRect().width
      }px`;
      if (movingAhead) {
        navLine.style.left = `${currentLink.offsetLeft}px`;
      }
    }, 700);
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  color: #444;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navigation {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  top: -0.5px;
  background-color: #edece8;
  margin: 60px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation__link {
  color: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px (20px * 2) 0 (20px * 2);
  position: relative;
}

.navigation__line {
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  background: red;
  // width: calc(100% - 80px);
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.navigation__item {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Consectetur adipiscing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Donec ut</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a class="navigation__link" href="#">Placerat dignissim</a>
    </li>
    <div class="navigation__line"></div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is great, but I would like to match the original codepen where if you go from link 1 to link 5, it spans the entire length, so in that regard it needs to also add the width of all the links between.

Comment: I noticed that after I posted. I just updated the answer to account for that.

Comment: @HK Well, it works. But it has some serious bugs.  Like, the line gets too long before getting back to link's width (in the first run). Just try making the 1st click on the last link.